# How to choose result queue for celery task?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

Here is my celery config:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT='amqp',
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://',
```

I am sending task to execute this way:

```
result = my_function.apply_async(('arguments here',), queue='queue_123')
```

Celery works as expected, I see this tasks in "queue_123".

Now I need to get all results of execution to queue "my_result_queue". How can I do it?

Celery now creates new queue with name like "19b7013a-a077-3d2a-b60a-d57c51d5d30c" and inserts results to it. I need to fix this behavior and insert results to queue with specified name.

I need something like this:

```
result = my_function.apply_async(('arguments here',), queue='queue_123', results_queue='my_result_queue')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@app.task(reply_to='result_queue)`